# Year tab in Users tab displays wrong reputation for some users

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, users

The **year** tab in the **Users** tab displays wrong reputation for some users.

You can see some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=1&tab=reputation&filter=year) :

[image]

I marked a few users, but actually all the users on the first several pages show wrong reputation values. Those values are close to the reputation these users gained last year (2015).

The interesting part about this bug is that not all users show rep values of last year. You can see that I'm ranked 3rd on the list, which I can only dream of. My actual rank last year was 12.

If I search for some users that out-ranked me last year, such as Jon Skeet, I see that his yearly reputation shows the correct value for 2016 :

[image]

Another example of a user with the correct 2016 rep :

[image]

Oh, and I checked a couple of other sites (SciFi and MetaSE) and didn't see that bug there.

Comment: A workaround until this is addressed would be to use the quarter stats.  They will completely agree with the year-to-date statistics for three months.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yes, I realized that myself :)

Comment: i'm sure you found it when you're searching your name :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The job timed out resetting the year column, so I ran a manual sync up just now piggybacking on the `ReputationMonth` column since they should match at the moment (and a sanity check of the data confirms `ReputationMonth` is correct).

The way this system works is a bit of trade-off in obscurity vs. performance. when we update reputation on a user, that one column delta is replicated via a trigger to additional `ReputationX` columns: `Day`, `Week`, `Month`, `Quarter`, and `Year` also on the `Users` table. This is incredibly efficient. The downside is that it relies on a scheduled task at Midnight to reset the proper intervals every night. In the case of `ReputationYear`, this was a large enough update to deadlock and rollback last night.

For the worriers: in the worst of cases we can just perform a global rep recalc which would be invisible to users besides fixing these columns and downstream issues like this question.